# Print values from multidimensional array into a table, no duplicates

Tags: php

I have this array that looks like below. I want to output data in a table where I output all the hours under each project. So for each Project It should create a new "<*tr>", but also If there is a Activity => "Sick".

I need to get unique data and no duplicates. Can't seem to set up my loop in a correct way for it to work with creating my table.

I can do a standard foreach like this:

```
 foreach ($array as $key => $value)

 <tr>
  <td><?php echo $value['Aktivity'];?></td>
  <td><?php echo $value['Project']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $value['Hours'] ?></td>
 </tr>
```

Which gives me:

```
Work | Project 1 | 8
Work | Project 2 | 8
Work | Project 1 | 5
Sick |           | 8
```

I want it to be like this below, no duplicates, but I dont know where to start. I was trying to chunk out my array with array_column and then doing an array_unique to get only one of each Project which works. But then I only get one of the values I need. I would like to keep it in my original array and loop through it, if it is possible.

```
Work | Project 1 | 8
Work | Project 2 | 13
Sick |           | 8



 array(4) {
 [0]=>
   array(3) {
    ["Activity"] => "Work"
    ["Project"] => "Projekt 1"
    ["Hours"] => "8"

 [1]=>
   array(3) {
    ["Activity"] => "Work"
    ["Project"] => "Projekt 2"
    ["Hours"] => "8"

 [2]=>
   array(3) {
    ["Activity"] => "Work"
    ["Project"] => "Projekt 1"
        ["Hours"] => "5"
 [3]=>
   array(3) {
    ["Activity"] => "Sick"
    ["Project"] => ""
    ["Hours"] => "8"
```

Comment: like @Karl said show us an error or an attempt of doing it, don't come on here expecting people to write your code for you. how are you going to learn ?

Comment: Updated my question, sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem.

The first thing to do is count the rows, so in your case thats 4. Now you know how many times you have to run the loop.

```
$result = count($yourarray);

for($i = 0; $i < $result; i++)
```

In the loop you add something like, to print the name of the project(in the `echo` you also add your table parts like `<tr>` and `<td>`.

```
if($i == 0){echo yourarray[$i]['Projekt']}
```

Then you want to do the same but this time the activity

```
 if($i == 0){echo yourarray[$i]['Activity']}
```

and Hours

```
if($i == 0){echo yourarray[$i]['Hours']}
```